# Differential equations with rational functions as solution

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, special-functions

I have some families of nonlinear, first order differential equations. When I try to use `DSolve`, I usually get a mess (if anything at all) in terms of `InverseFunction`s and `Solve`, but I know that my equations always have a rational function as a solution; I just want to know what it is.

If I put a small bound on the degree, I can write the solution out in terms of unknown coefficients, substitute, expand and collect terms, and solve the resulting system of equations (by hand, even).

But clearly this is unsustainable as the degree goes up and even intractable to do by computer. Is there a better way to solve these kinds of differential equation in *Mathematica*, perhaps somehow telling it the solution will be of this form? For example

```
DSolve[(x + x^10) == f'[x] (x + f[x]^10), f[x], x]
```

doesn't even return anything. But $f(x)=x$ is a solution. Similarly,

```
DSolve[(x + x^2) == f'[x]*(x^2 + f[x]), f[x], x]
```

returns

```
Solve[C[1] == (x BesselJ[1, 2 I Sqrt[x - f[x]]] + 
  I BesselJ[2, 2 I Sqrt[x - f[x]]] Sqrt[x - f[x]])/(
    x BesselY[1, -2 I Sqrt[x - f[x]]] - 
     I BesselY[2, -2 I Sqrt[x - f[x]]] Sqrt[x - f[x]]), f[x]]
```

but $f(x)=x$ is also a solution. In general I would like to handle higher powers of $f'(x)$ as well. But I'd like to figure out simple cases first. Some more examples:

```
DSolve[ (1 + x^5) == (f'[x])^10*(1 + f[x]^5), f[x], x]
```

has $f(x) = x$ as a solution, but `DSolve` gives some mess like:

```
f[x] -> InverseFunction[
   1/3 #1 (Hypergeometric2F1[1/5, 9/10, 6/5, -#1^5] + 
       2 (1 + #1^5)^(1/10)) &][
  C[1] - 1/3 x (2 (1 + x^5)^(1/10) + 
      Hypergeometric2F1[1/5, 9/10, 6/5, -x^5])]
```

which I'm sure is accurate, but not so useful to me. Finally,

```
DSolve[1 + x^3 == (x^7) (f'[x])^2 + x*f[x], f[x], x]
```

has solution $f(x) = 1/x$, but `DSolve` doesn't give any output.

Comment: Difficult to say much without a specific Mathematica input.

Comment: Thanks. I added two examples, which are more simple than what I'm trying to solve more generally. But I would be happy if I could even get those solved.

Comment: I'm mostly interested in if there is some way to 'hint' to Mathematica (or some other package) that I only want rational functions as solutions.

Comment: _Write the solution out in terms of unknown coefficients, substitute, expand and collect terms, and solve the resulting system of equations_ is the only approach I can think out, and I think it should work when the degree isn't _too_ high. Can you show an example that is hard to handle with this approach?

Comment: Maybe I'm just not doing it the right way, then. For example, $961 x^{96} - 899 x^{64} - 61 x^{32} -1 = (x^5)*f'(x)^2 * (1 + f(x))$ has solution $(x^{32}-x-1)/x$. But if all I know is that the solution is degree 32, then I have 64 unknowns, and running Expand, Collect, Coefficient, Numerator, Simplify, etc on that expression shows no sign of stopping. It's a lot of terms when it's expanded out. I suppose I could try to let it run overnight.

Comment: Is it the case that the rational function is a special solution? DSolve usually tries to find a general solution.

Comment: I need to look at this closer, but here's a [paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4194307/) on using Pade approximants for solving nonlinear differential equations.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I completely expect that these rational solutions are special cases only and that the general solution may be highly non-rational. However, I want to focus on those solutions that are rational (and polynomials when possible, though this is rarer) because those are naturally easier to work with. Of course, I will take "whatever I can get" if it's easier to work with than the implicit solutions that DSolve tends to give.

Comment: Also, I have accepted Bruno's answer, but I will continue to appreciate any other answers to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea how robust the following code is.  The idea is to search for singular points and then write f as a polynomial times whatever singularities we found.  The degree of the polynomial is bounded by looking at the behaviour at infinity.  I've included a last step which checks that the function is a solution, to avoid returning too much junk in case the differential equation did not have a rational solution.

First a tool to solve iteratively a system in which the first equation fixes the first variable, the first two fix the first two etc.

```
ClearAll[specialsolve];
specialsolve::toomanyvars = "Extra vars `1`.  Rules found: `2`.";
specialsolve[eqs_List, {}, rules_List] := 
 If[And @@ (eqs /. 
     rules), {rules}, {}, {}]; (*Returns a set of solutions.*)
specialsolve[{}, vars_List, rules_List] := 
 Message[specialsolve::toomanyvars, vars, rules];
specialsolve[eqs_List, vars_List, rules_List] :=
  Join @@ 
   Map[specialsolve[Rest[eqs], Rest[vars], Join[rules, #]] &, 
    Solve[eqs[[1]] /. rules, vars[[1]]]];
```

Next, the horrible code.

```
ClearAll[rationalDSolve];
rationalDSolve[eq_] := 
 Module[{terms, coefs, powers, specialas, valuesofbforgenerica, 
   valuesofbforspecialas, valuesofbanda, valuesint, 
   inversedenominator, powersnearinfinity, maxpower, coefseqs, 
   solutions},
  (*Use a toy Ansatz of f[x]=c(x-a)^
  b to find behaviour near some point x\[Equal]a.*)
  terms = 
   Expand[eq /. f :> (c (# - a)^b &) /. x :> y + a] /. 
    HoldPattern[Plus[t___] | t___] :> {t};
  coefs = Replace[terms, {p_. y^(q_: 1) :> {q, p}, p_ :> {0, p}}, {1}];
  powers = List @@ Simplify[Min[coefs[[All, 1]]]];
  (*We've found the list of posisble leading powers of y=(x-
  a) for generic a (which one in this list is really the leading \
power depends on b.  
  Determine values of a for which the coefficient of one of these \
powers vanishes.*)
  specialas = 
   DeleteDuplicates[
    Flatten[Map[Solve[Coefficient[Plus @@ terms, y, #] == 0, a] &, 
      powers]]];
  (*For generic a, 
  values of b for which two terms turn out to have the same power are \
candidates for cancellations.  TODO: 
  check that the resulting power is indeed the minimum, 
  otherwise these solutions are useless (but not harmful).*)
  valuesofbforgenerica = 
   Flatten[Map[Solve[Equal @@ #, b] &, Subsets[powers, {2}]], {1, 2}];
  (*For special a, same story.  
  There is probably a more efficient way of doing all that.*)
  valuesofbforspecialas = Flatten[
    specialas /. (a -> val_) :>
      With[{terms = 
         Expand[eq /. f :> (c (# - val)^b &) /. x :> y + val] /. 
          HoldPattern[Plus[t___] | t___] :> {t}},
       With[{coefs = 
          Replace[terms, {p_. y^(q_: 1) :> {q, p}, 
            p_ :> {0, p}}, {1}]},
        With[{powers = List @@ Simplify[Min[coefs[[All, 1]]]]},
         Flatten[
          Map[Solve[{a == val, Equal @@ #}, {a, b}] &, 
           Subsets[powers, {2}]], {1, 2}]]]], {1, 2}];
  (*List of lists of rules {...,{a\[Rule]-1,b\[Rule]3/2},{a\[Rule]-I,
  b\[Rule]3/2},...} for possible leading behaviours.*)
  valuesofbanda = Join[valuesofbforgenerica, valuesofbforspecialas];
  (*Let's focus on solutions that are rational functions, 
  so only integer b.  Also we only care about singularities so b<0.*)


  valuesint = 
   Cases[valuesofbanda, {___, b -> n_Integer?Negative, ___}];
  inversedenominator = Product[(x - a)^b /. vals, {vals, valuesint}];
  (*Powers near x\[Rule]Infinity.  
  Now the dominant power is the Max.  
  Directly solve for b integer (we assume rational functions).  
  We care about the maximum possible exponent so take Max afterwards \
too.*)
  powersnearinfinity = List @@ Simplify[Max[coefs[[All, 1]]]];
  maxpower = 
   Max[b /. 
      Flatten[Map[Solve[Equal @@ #, b, Integers] &, 
        Subsets[powersnearinfinity, {2}]], {1, 2}]] + 
    Sum[-b /. val, {val, valuesint}];
  coefseqs = 
   Map[# == 0 &, 
    CoefficientList[
     eq /. f :> (Sum[
            a[i] #^i, {i, 0, maxpower}] inversedenominator /. 
          x -> # &), x]];
  solutions = 
   inversedenominator Sum[a[i] x^i, {i, 0, maxpower}] /. 
    specialsolve[coefseqs, Table[a[i], {i, 0, maxpower}], {}];
  Cases[solutions, 
   sol_ /; FullSimplify[0 == eq /. f :> (sol /. x -> # &)]]]
```

Let's test.

```
In[86]:= rationalDSolve[961 x^96 - 899 x^64 - 61 x^32 - 1 - x^5 f'[x]^2 (1 + f[x])]

Out[86]= {(-1 - x + x^32)/x,
  ((-1)^(1/3) - x - (-1)^(1/3) x^32)/x,
  (-(-1)^(2/3) - x + (-1)^(2/3) x^32)/x}
```

This takes a couple seconds on my desktop.  Be patient.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very much in the direction of what I was looking for. The fact that it can handle the higher degree cases is very useful. I will have to experiment more with this and see what it can do.